# What is the specilized index of a given class diagram

Tags: uml, metrics, software-design, object-oriented-analysis, maintainability

What is the specialized index SIX of a given class diagram,I need a good and clear definition. 
What is the range of values that considered as low value of SIX, what is the range of values that considered as high value of SIX and what is the range of values that considered as medium value of SIX.

What is the impact of SIX on the maintainability of the object oriented software system.

The following is a link that contains some information about this topic, but it is not sufficient:

[SIX - Specialized Index](http://support.objecteering.com/objecteering6.1/help/us/metrics/metrics_in_detail/specialization_index.htm)

Comment: You mean Six Sigma, don't you?

Comment: @ThomasKilian : No, it is something we need to measure it for a class in the model because the override methods are presented in a fairly deep level in the inheritance hierarchy!

Comment: Then, what is SIX?

Comment: This is my question, I need to get a very clear definition for such UML class diagram metric

Comment: I have never heard that acronym (?). If you are not referring Six Sigma, I have no idea what you are asking for,

Comment: Do you have any examples or links that can help folks here better understand what you're asking about?

Comment: @RishiB :: I have added a link.